# Extjs + D3; Load and draw onto image

Tags: javascript, d3.js, extjs

I would like to load an image (jpg/png) within an Ext panel and then draw lines/markups/icons ontop of that image using D3. I've tried two approaches but none of them worked. On both approaches I use these listeneres to trigger the same function ('renderMap') that then tries to load the image and draw on it:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: 'renderMap',
    resize: 'renderMap'
}
```

Test 1: Use an empty Ext panel and let D3 load the image. Result: this loads the image (I can see that the browser is actually retrieving the jpg) but doesn't present it on screen (tested with Chrome and IE).

```
var the_id = "#" + panel.getId();

var svg = d3.select(the_id).append('svg').attr({
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      border: '1px solid #ccc'
    });

svg.append('svg:image')
    .attr({
      'xlink:href': 'http://localhost/map/test.jpg',
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: 128,
      height: 128
    });
```

Test 2: Load the image using Extjs first

```
init: function() {

    var image = Ext.create({
        xtype: 'image',
        src: 'http://localhost/map/test.jpg', 
        style:'background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: auto 100%;background-position: center;'
    });

    this.getView().add(image);
```

Then lookup the newly added image and try to use this for some drawing with D3 within the renderMap function:

```
renderMap: function (panel) {

    var image = panel.down('image')
    var the_id = "#" + image.getId();
    var rectsize = 100;

    var svg = d3.select(the_id)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("height", rectsize*10)
            .attr("width", rectsize*10);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", rectsize)
            .attr("height", rectsize)
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return  i*(rectsize + 2); })
            .attr("y", function(d, i) { return rectsize; })
            .style("fill", "yellow")
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", "5px");
```

This successfully loads the image but draws nothing ontop of it...
Any help is highly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: first, i think `svg.selecAll("rect")`is not getting anything because there is no "rectangle" inside svg.. can you confirm that by `console.log(svg);` ?

Comment: thanks for spotting this. `svg.selectAll("rect")` retrieves is empty. I tried to change this to `svg.append("rect").attr("width", rectsize)...` but still no rectangles appear on top of the loaded image

Answer (score 2):

In `Ext image = panel.down('image')` returns an `Ext.Element` and **d3** requires a `dom`.

Use:

```
renderMap: function (panel) {

var image = panel.down('image').el.dom;
var rectsize = 100;

var svg = d3.select(image)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("height", rectsize*10)
        .attr("width", rectsize*10);
```

Comment: thanks. I still don't see any rectangle appearing on top of my loaded image. But when I look at my Ext panel object using console, I can see the svg within the panel under `Panel.items.items[0].el.dom.children`: [Screenshot: SVG](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjys7xzdfvf3rq7/Untitled.png?dl=0):
The second screenshot shows the rect within the svg: [Screenshot: RECT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pl1dm9knbdjhqo/Untitled1.png?dl=0)

Comment: That is the normal behavior if you append the svg to an image. You may consider adding that image inside the svg OR remove the image from the panel container add the svg and add the image back to the svg at the desired depth. 
It really depends on your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments from Geoman Yabes and bluehipy I figured out how to make it work. Since bluehipy's answer doesn't provide the full logic that I needed to get it all working and I wanted to share what works for me I'm answering my own question but will up-vote the other answer and especially bluehpy's comment that I needed to add the image inside the svg and then add the circle (other drawings) inside that svg as well. 
Here is my code:

```
var w = panel.getWidth();
var h = panel.getHeight();

// The DOM of the panel's body
var panelBodyDom = panel.body.el.dom;

var colors = d3.scale.category10();

// clear everything and reload
d3.select(panelBodyDom).selectAll("div").remove();

var svg_div_container = d3.select(panelBodyDom).append("div").attr({
    class:  "chart",
    width:  w + "px",
    height: h + "px",
    style:  "vertical-align:left",
    align:  "left"
});

var svg = svg_div_container.append('svg').attr({
    width:  w,
    height: h,
    border: '1px solid #ccc'
});

var svg_image = svg.append('svg:image')
.attr({
  'xlink:href': 'http://localhost/map/' + view.config.mapId + '.jpg', 
  'x': 0,
  'y': 0,
  'width': w,
  'height': h,
  'style': 'vertical-align:left',
  'align' : 'left'
});

svg.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", h/3)
    .attr("cx", w/2)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .style("fill",colors(h));
```

Now I need to figure out how to make the image left-aligned. Whatever I do the image is placed in the center of the svg/div. But I will create another question if I can't figure it out myself.
Thanks guys for the answer and comments leading to the solution!